# Facebook fail to publish when not supporting SSO and external safari (inline dialog)

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Follow those steps:

1) On "Facebook.m" set the call to "authorizeWithFBAppAuth" at authorize to 
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]; 

2) Start the app, login to Facebook, try to publish a stream via the FBDialog (its working).

3) Exit the app (Stop execution).

4) Open the app (FBSession STILL valid), try to publish another stream and you will get an error message.



* I can still publish with the graph API, but my client persist on publishing via the official Facebook dialog.

* I noticed that some cookies were missing from the first fbDidLogin call to the next time i opened the app. Therefore i guess that the FBDialog miss some vital cookies.

* I don't think its a 'good' workaround to persist the cookies (as Facebook can change their calls and we will be ducked :)


Of course when i tried the normal SSO it worked.

Please help!